# How to tell if the directory_entry is the end of directory_iterator in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

using `std::filesystem`, how can I tell that the `directory_entry` is the end of a `directory_iterator`?

here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```cpp
auto it = fs::directory_iterator(path);
for (const auto &i : it) {
  if (i == it.back()) { // this works with `vector`s but not with `directory_iterator`
    doSomethingWith(i); // call this function only on the last entry.
  }
}
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work about it?

Comment: @Carlos `back` is not a member of `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`!!

Comment: If you had `back` you wouldn't need the loop at all!

Comment: You just have to remember each one you see in a variable _outside_ the loop and after the loop exits, there it will be. But my guess is that whatever you're thinking of doing can't be solved this way.  The order of entries returned by a directory iterator is _unspecified_: It might not even be the same on two subsequent calls - even if the directory is unmodified!  It certainly will not need to match any _other_ kind of ordering, whether alphabetical, or the one the operating system gives you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) -

> If the directory_iterator reports an error or is advanced past the last directory entry, it becomes equal to the default-constructed iterator, also known as the end iterator. Two end iterators are always equal, dereferencing or incrementing the end iterator is undefined behavior.

However, the issue is incrementing `directory_iterator` [invalidates all previous values](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/increment).

So, one possible solution is to use the `post-increment` operation to find the last `directory_entry`.

```
auto it = fs::directory_iterator(path);
for (auto i = fs::begin(it); fs::begin(i) != fs::end(it); ) {
  auto entry = *(i++);
  if (fs::begin(i) == fs::end(it)) { // sugercoat of `i == fs::directory_iterator{}`
    doSomethingWith(entry); // this is the last directory entry
  } else {
    doSomethingElse(entry); // non-last entry
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::filesystem::end`. See the docs here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin

But in your example, you shouldn’t need to explicitly check as the loop will end correctly on its own.

Comment: `std::filesystem::end(directory_iterator)` returns a new `directory_iterator` not `directory_entry`, any hint how to use it, thanks?

and, I don't want to check to end the loop, I want to process the end of the `iter` differently, like `if (end) { doSomeThing(i) } else {doSomeThingElse(i) }`,

Comment: @AhmedKamal I think you should edit your question and add that you want to process the last item in the directory differently than the rest.

Answer (score 1):

A default constructed `directory_iterator` is the end iterator. See entry one in the constructor list: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/directory_iterator